# Does Kotlin have functional List data structure?

Tags: scala, kotlin, functional-programming

Scala, for example, has functional List data structure that has O(1) for adding new item on head with Cons(::) operator.

But, + operator of List in Kotlin works in that it creates new list object bigger-sized by 1 and copies all original items to it, adds new item, and returns it. So addition operation takes O(N).

Is there any immutable List data structure with O(1) for append in Kotlin?

Comment: Not that I know of, though it's not that difficult to write such a data structure yourself. One `sealed class` and a pair of subclasses, one for nil and the other for cons.

Comment: You're right, but I don't want to write all of the util functions for that by myself, for example reduce/fold/map/take/drop/max/sum....

Comment: There's this official JetBrains library that might help? https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.collections.immutable

Answer (score 2):

No, the kotlin standard library does not have that. You can write your own cons list though.

> but I don't want to write all of the util functions for that by myself, for example reduce/fold/map/take/drop/max/sum....

You can get those functions for free just by implementing `Iterable`. For a cons list, this is easy to do:

```
sealed class ConsList<out T>: Iterable<T> {
    object Nil : ConsList<Nothing>() {
        override fun iterator() = object : Iterator<Nothing> {
            override fun hasNext() = false
            override fun next() = throw NoSuchElementException()
        }
    }

    data class Cons<out T>(val element: T, val rest: ConsList<T>): ConsList<T>() {
        override fun iterator() = iterator {
            yield(element)
            yieldAll(rest)
        }

    }
}
```

Note that implementing `List` involves quite a lot more code, especially the `listIterator` and `sublist` methods. You *could* use the some of the default `AbstractList` implementations, but it wouldn't be terribly efficient.